# How do I create stack navigation tabs for a separate .tsx file in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

At the start of my application, there is two tabs at the bottom of the screen (these tabs came in the template I downloaded from Expo for react js). I made a new screen, called homepage, and I want to now replicate those same tabs at the bottom, but I can't figure out how. I tried using a stack navigator but it did not work.

I want it to look like this [image: js]

Here is my code for homescreen

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import FAQ_Screen from './FAQ_Screen';
import NewsScreen from './NewsScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import BottomTabNavigator from '../navigation/BottomTabNavigator';
import NotFoundScreen from './NotFoundScreen';



const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function HomeScreen() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Home </Text>

        <select> 

          <option> Station 1 </option>
          <option> Staton 2 </option>

        </select>

    </View>

    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: '80%',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare tabs inside `Tab.Navigator`.

These screens can be separate `.tsx` or `js` files. I did using `js`, to be able to show using Expo. However, `ts/js` doesn't change the behavior.

I did a working example:

https://snack.expo.io/@mayconjcm/tab-navigation-%7C-react-navigation

You can also see the code here:

Home:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeTab from './Tab1';
import SettingsTab from './Tab2';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTab} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsTab} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Tab1:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const HomeTab = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default HomeTab;
```

Tab2:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const SettingsTab = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default SettingsTab;
```

Comment: Hey Maycon, thanks for your response. I have implemented the tabs and they work. However, I was just wondering how I can get rid of the small display and instead render a completely different, new page when I click on "Home" or "News" tab  https://ibb.co/g6VSwb1

Comment: You would need to manage the "display" using a react state, so you won't need react-navigation to do that.

Comment: is there a guide I can follow? I am a complete novice so not sure what to do

Comment: any help @Maycon Mesquita

Comment: @henry this tutorials show how to create Tabs using react state only. It was built with react.js, but you can replace web tags (eg: <div> to <View>) to make this work great.

Comment: If you need a elegant solution, you can try this component: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view